# How to absolute-position an image to the bottom without squeezing it?

Tags: html, css

I am currently a newbie to front-end development, my very first project is a single page RWD portfolio site.

I have a layout which is my own photo will be at the very bottom centered on my site while the menu is on the top. I have tried many ways and searched online for a good way that I don't squeeze my picture when I adjust the height of my site, but I never found the answer.

I've also tried adding padding, additional divs with fixed width/height to make it perform normally, but apparently they won't work well on all the resolutions. Not only that, but I've tested with "width=100vh" and other similar methods online, but it still doesn't work.

```css
.totallayout{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:
}
.imgexample{
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  background-color:#E98295;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<div class="totallayout">


<div class="container-fluid">
<p class="display-4 text-center text-nowrap">
Header
</p>
<div class="container-fluid" style="position:absolute; bottom:0; background-color:#82E9DE">
when you readjust the height of the screen <br> <br>, two divs will suqeeze together
<div class="imgexample">MY photo here

</div>

</div>
</div>
```

here's the jsfiddle I created for making my question more specific and clear

https://jsfiddle.net/visa2006/k2o7ntqm/7/

Is there any way I can make it stick to the bottom while maintaining the space in between?

Thank you for the attention and answer.

Comment: can you explain your question more specifically!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds harsh but with the best intention to get you on the right track for the future: Learn to program clean.

- Means give the right spacing for every tag and closign tag so you can easily see which closing tag belongs to what starting tag.
- Dont mix styling in CSS and in the HTML code. Best only do styling in CSS. otherwise you have a mess editing later on. And you lsoe track on larger projects.

I wrote the right framework for you. You have a header box, the content box and the footer box. The footer box incldues your foto. the footer box is set to a height auf the photo and attached and fixed to the bottom. So it always will stay there. **The footer box will need the same color as your background. Not transparent!** Otherwise the content will dispaly through the footer.

so that you can see the whole content and parts of the content is not cut off, the **content box needs a bottom margin of at least the footer box height.**

Means give the right spacing for every tag and closign tag so you can easily see which closing tag belongs to what starting tag.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #82E9DE;
  margin: 0 0 90px 0;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: orange;
}

#photo {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #E98295;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      <p>Header<p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>when you readjust the height of the screen,</p>
      <p>two divs will squeeze together.</p>
      <br>
      <p>Random testing text:<p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div id="photo">My photo here</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I'll work on it, but the the problem my problem is not making my photo stick to the bottom of the window but to the page, however, I've finally found a solution is that I make my totallayout with min-width so when I resize the height, my elements won't be squeezed

Comment: In that case, it would be better to use a grid. That way the design can be 100% responsive even for Mobile use. Alternative use my code and remove in css the lines #footer position fixed, bottom: 0 and z-index.